# Npm install tries to install from localhost

Tags: npm, npm-install

When I try to run the comman

```
npm install http
```

It hangs for a while before giving me this error

```
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://localhost/http failed, reason:
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Barth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR!     at _destroy (node:_http_client:875:13)
npm ERR!     at onSocketNT (node:_http_client:895:5)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR!  FetchError: request to https://localhost/http failed, reason:
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Barth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR!     at _destroy (node:_http_client:875:13)
npm ERR!     at onSocketNT (node:_http_client:895:5)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   type: 'system',
npm ERR!   requiredBy: '.'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

as you can see it tries to install it from https://localhost/http
what is causing this and how do I fix this

I have already tried reinstaling node altogether

Comment: What does `npm config get registry` return?

Comment: "https://localhost"

Comment: Can you try settings registry with `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` this command?

Comment: I've been able to reset it, thanks just did not know where to look

the fix was npm set registy 
(noting after it so it reset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that your npm registry is set correctly. You can check and update the registry using the following commands:

`npm config get registry`

`npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

I hope that will help to others too.